# Product url key doesn't update

Tags: magento-1.7, redirect

I am experiencing a really weird issue: When I modify a product URL key in backend, redirect from old URL doesn't apply. Valid URL is still the old one, in spite of new one is shown in backend. If i type in my browser the new URL, i get **404 error**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you changed the URL in the correct Current Configuration Scope? This only applies if you run a multi-store.

More on Configuration Scope: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/configuration/scope.html

Comment: Starting from what you said, i realised that failing products had unchecked "Use default value" in one of my store views. Checking it, works fine.

Comment: Nice one. I'm glad I could assist :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the URL index is not updated yet. Go to *System > Index Management*, select the catalog URL rewrite index and then select "refresh" from the actions menu.

Comment: I tried reindexing (using backend and magerun), but issue persists.